# std::ofstream - setting seekp to wrong position

Tags: c++, file, exception, error-handling, ofstream

I have read information from cpp reference, but I could not find answear for my question. I want to know what is guaranteed to happen if I have empty file and try to write something at unexisting position, like that:

```
std::ofstream stream(path);
stream.seekp(1234);
stream.write(whatever, sizeof(whatever));
```

I am asking my question due to exception handling.

Comment: This is more an operating-system dependent thing.

Comment: When you create a new empty file, everything is an "unexisting position". It is not *that* special to start to write only from the beginning. Some operating systems will keep just the parts you have written as a [sparse file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file). Others might fill out the holes on disk with some padding, like zeros.

Comment: tell and seek are interesting at the best of times. There are no guarantees that the numbers they use make much sense. All that's guaranteed is if you use the same number on the same stream you get the same place in the stream, if that place still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I've just debug it :

```
  #include <fstream>      // std::ofstream
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;
  int main () {

  std::ofstream outfile;
  outfile.open ("C:\\Users\\Mohammad\\Desktop\\test.txt");
  outfile.seekp(1234);
  if (outfile.is_open())
  {
  outfile.write ("This is an apple",16);
  outfile.write (" sam",4);
  outfile.close();
  cout<<"done";
  }
  if(!outfile)
   {
   cout<<"error!";
   }
   return 0;
   }
```

and result is "done" in console without any error.
even when the file doesn't exist in the path it doesn't have any error.

compile photo :
https://pasteboard.co/HsWql4y.png

Comment: dude ! i've just compile it

Comment: @Kasata Ata , i've just made it easy to you to compile it and change the code to get what you want.

Comment: When I ran a modified version on Windows (g++4.9), that's really similar to the current edit, I got a file full of nulls that ends with the data written right where I placed it. The thing is you can't count on this behaviour.  Precisely what is going to happen is not defined by the C++ Standard.